# VM aborting after I extended the Dalvik internal data structure “Object”

Tags: android, dalvik

I need to add an additional filed in the Dalvik internal data structure Object in dalvik/vm/oo/Object.h. And I modified the asm offset in dalvik/vm/mterp/common/asm-constants.h accordingly.
**(Is there any other files I have to modify ? Thanks in advance )**

The building was successfully, but the system cannot run on NEXUS 4 with the flowing log:

```
278 W/dalvikvm(17272): DexOpt: --- END 'voip-common.jar' --- status=0x000b, process failed
279 E/dalvikvm(17272): Unable to extract+optimize DEX from '/system/framework/voip-common.jar'
280 D/dalvikvm(17272): Unable to process classpath element '/system/framework/voip-common.jar'
281 D/dalvikvm(17272): DexOpt: incorrect opt magic number (0xff ff ff ff)
282 D/dalvikvm(17272): ODEX file is stale or bad; removing and retrying (/data/dalvik-cache/system@framework@mms-common.jar@classes.dex)
283 D/dalvikvm(17272): DexOpt: --- BEGIN 'mms-common.jar' (bootstrap=1) ---
284 E/dalvikvm(17332): Fatal error: java/lang/Object
285 E/dalvikvm(17332): VM aborting
286 F/libc    (17332): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadd00d (code=1), thread 17332 (dexopt)
287 I/DEBUG   (  170): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
```

and

```
563 W/dalvikvm(17272): DexOpt: --- END 'mms-common.jar' --- status=0x000b, process failed
564 E/dalvikvm(17272): Unable to extract+optimize DEX from '/system/framework/mms-common.jar'
565 D/dalvikvm(17272): Unable to process classpath element '/system/framework/mms-common.jar'
566 D/dalvikvm(17272): DexOpt: incorrect opt magic number (0xff ff ff ff)
567 D/dalvikvm(17272): ODEX file is stale or bad; removing and retrying (/data/dalvik-cache/system@framework@android.policy.jar@classes.          dex)
568 D/dalvikvm(17272): DexOpt: --- BEGIN 'android.policy.jar' (bootstrap=1) ---
569 E/dalvikvm(17333): Fatal error: java/lang/Object
570 E/dalvikvm(17333): VM aborting
571 F/libc    (17333): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadd00d (code=1), thread 17333 (dexopt)
572 I/DEBUG   (  170): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
```

...

```
 2957 W/dalvikvm(17466): DexOpt: --- END 'framework.jar' --- status=0x000b, process failed
 2958 E/dalvikvm(17466): Unable to extract+optimize DEX from '/system/framework/framework.jar'
 2959 D/dalvikvm(17466): Unable to process classpath element '/system/framework/framework.jar'
 2960 D/dalvikvm(17466): DexOpt: incorrect opt magic number (0xff ff ff ff)
 2961 D/dalvikvm(17466): ODEX file is stale or bad; removing and retrying (/data/dalvik-cache/system@framework@telephony-common.jar@classes.        dex)
 2962 D/dalvikvm(17466): DexOpt: --- BEGIN 'telephony-common.jar' (bootstrap=1) ---
 2963 E/dalvikvm(17572): Fatal error: java/lang/Object
 2964 E/dalvikvm(17572): VM aborting
 2965 F/libc    (17572): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadd00d (code=1), thread 17572 (dexopt)
```

Comment: `55 # define STRING_FIELDOFF_VALUE      8
    56 # define STRING_FIELDOFF_HASHCODE   12 
    57 # define STRING_FIELDOFF_OFFSET     16
    58 # define STRING_FIELDOFF_COUNT      20`  in File /dalvik/vm/UtfString.h should also be modified accordingly.

Comment: You need to figure out where it's aborting; once you know that, the reason why should become obvious. The stack trace from the logs (which you didn't show in your question), combined with `addr2line`, should point you at the right spot.

Comment: To fadden: Thanks for your suggestion. This question was solved. I added a field in the basic nternal data structure 'Object', as a result , the values of the String field offsets have to be modified (in File /dalvik/vm/UtfString.h).